# Print variables on php excel

Tags: php, excel

I want to get data from database and save it as excel file.
What i got so far(creating connection and new phpexcel object):

```
$conn->set_charset('utf8_unicode_ci');//if not by default
// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$F = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
```

Then I am getting data from database:

```
// 1.Get data
// data for final table
// format is [username][projectNo] => [process1, process2, ..., processN]
$result = [];
// map project no to its title
$projectNoToTitle = [];
$sql = '
    SELECT uid, username
    FROM `user`
    ORDER BY username
';
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
// for each user
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
    $sql2 = '
        SELECT a.* FROM
        (
            (
              -- select pairs project - leader
              SELECT p.projectNo, p.title, CONCAT(pr.process, "(ld)") AS process
              FROM project p
                LEFT JOIN proc_leader pr ON p.projectNo = pr.projectNo
              AND pr.proc_leader = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data['username']) . '"
            )
            -- union all means we union result of queries, which have structure
            -- and don\'t remove duplicates (it\'s faster than UNION and 
            -- more logical because in our sittuation it won\'t be any duplicates) 
            UNION ALL 
            (
              -- select pairs project - checker
              SELECT p.projectNo, p.title, CONCAT(pch.process, "(chk)") AS process
              FROM project p
                LEFT JOIN proc_checker pch ON p.projectNo = pch.projectNo
              AND pch.proc_checker = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data['username']) . '"  
            )
            UNION ALL 
            (
              -- select pairs project - checker
              SELECT p.projectNo, p.title, CONCAT(pch.process, "(staff)") AS process
              FROM project p
                LEFT JOIN proc_staff pch ON p.projectNo = pch.projectNo
              AND pch.proc_staff = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data['username']) . '"  
            )           
        ) AS a
            ORDER BY a.projectNo
        ';
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    // for each project => process pair of user
    while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
        $username = $data['username'];
        $projectNo = $data2['projectNo'];
        $projectTitle = $data2['title'];
        $process = $data2['process'];

        $projectNoToTitle[$projectNo] = $projectTitle;

        if (!isset($result[$username])) {
            $result[$username] = [];
        }
        if (!isset($result[$username][$projectNo])) {
            $result[$username][$projectNo] = [];
        }
        if ($process) {
            $result[$username][$projectNo][] = $process;
        }
    }
}
```

And then I want to print received data into excel table:

```
$Letter='B';
$Number=2;  
$F = $objPHPExcel->createSheet(); //Setting index when creating
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);

// 2. Output data

if ($result) 
{
        // output body
        $body = '';
        foreach ($result as $username => $usernameData) {
            $row = '' . htmlspecialchars($username) . '';
            $F->setCellValue('A'.$Number, $row);
            foreach ($projectNoToTitle as $projectNo => $projectTitle) {
                $r = isset($usernameData[$projectNo])
                    ? implode(', ', $usernameData[$projectNo])
                    : 'N/A';
                $row .= '' . htmlspecialchars($r) . '';
            }
            $body .= $row;
        }

    $F->setCellValue('A'.'1', 'username');

    $F->fromArray($projectNoToTitle, null, 'B1');


    $F->getRowDimension($Number)->setRowHeight(20);
    $F->getColumnDimension($Letter)->setWidth(40);  
    $F->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(30);              
    ++$Number;
    ++$Letter;

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="HeadCount.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;   
}
```

I tried to print `body` but it gives me all info in one cell. Like [image: here]
If I am printing only `row` I got only one [image: name]
How can I print all neccessary data? I need smth like [image: this] but in excel. I know I can save table I got as excel, but the thing is I will need add more info later so I want to do it using phpexcel. Thanks for any help

Comment: you need to set the cell values inside the loop

Comment: like @nogad stated you must set each cell individually. You don't need to concat a huge string together. Looks like you're also never doing anything with `$body` anyway

Comment: @nogad what kind of loop? what should I loop?

Comment: @Cfreak yeah, I tried to print it and I got all information in one cell like on first screenshot

Comment: you already have the loop

Comment: @nogad you mean I need to put $F->setCellValue('A'.$Number, $row); inside foreach? see edited code